# When faceting with ggplot and plotly the points are plotted in the incorrect facet windows. How do i fix this?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, facet

I have a shiny app that plots data that is queried from our company database. You can choose to facet the plot based on different columns in the dataframe. I am using facet_grid and two selectInputs to facet from the side, top or both. I am also building a ggplot object and then using plotly_build to make a plotly plot in shiny.  I have tried to solve the problem outside of the shiny app by faceting `serialnumber ~ serialnumber`.

I am expecting to see the points being plotted in the facet windows diagonal, however it is just plotting in the first column all the way down. Here is the code I amusing to plot. I have changed all of the data because it is sensitive. This is only one example of this it presents in many other phenotypes. Also sorry for the mess of axis labels i was just trying to see if i could solve the problem and not making it look pretty. Let me know if there is anymore information you need?

```
gg_color_hue <- function(x){
  hues = seq(15,375, length = x+1)
  hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:x] 
}

ggplot(data= queryData, aes(x = AssayName, y = Metric, colour = SerialNumber)) +
 scale_colour_manual(values = gg_color_hue(length(unique(queryData$SerialNumber))),name = "SerialNumber") +
 facet_grid(SerialNumber ~  SerialNumber) +
 geom_point(size = 2) + 
 theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 12)) +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 2)) +
 labs(title = 'all assay') +
 xlab(paste("assays")) + 
 ylab("metric") +
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 32),
                 breaks = (seq(0,32, by = 5)))
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D8z4.png)
[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEExw.png)

Comment: I'm not sure why it happens, but I can reproduce your issue with the built-in `mtcars` data frame: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + facet_grid(cyl ~ cyl) + geom_point()`. Are you seeing the same issue when you facet on two different columns? Also, it looks like `SerialNumber` is coded as character or factor. If you want the facets ordered by magnitude, then convert to numeric.

Comment: Yeah this happens when I facet on two different columns, but i t is kind of random. I have tried to change the class from factor to numeric and even character. Sometimes it will plot correctly in ggplot, however when I use ggplotly to build a plotly object it will plot incorrectly.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data that reproduces this problem when run with your code? (Paste into your question the output of `dput(dataSample)`)

Comment: I added what the data frame look like. dput was too large.

Comment: A picture of the data frame is not useful. Please `dput` a *subset* of the data that reproduces your problem. You should only need a few rows as long as a few different values of each facet column are present.